# kill jquery cookies use null or empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

When handling jQuery cookies, I saw there are different approaches:

```
 $.cookie("fd_showFeatured","");
 $.cookie("wm_client_id", null);
```

is there any difference between those two methods or they are just same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same

1. setting empty string will give you empty string while reading it back which is a falsy value
2. setting null will give you 'null' string while reading it back which is a truthy value

But I think if you want to remove a cookie value use `$.removeCookie(name)`

```
$.removeCookie("wm_client_id", null);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RT2H2/)

Answer (score 0):

" " is an actual string, albeit an empty one.

null, however, means that the String variable points to nothing.

The result of your cookie approaches are the same.